# Visual Studio 2013 Graphics Diagnostics throws immediate access violation in dxgi.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, directx, directx-11, diagnostics

I am wanting to use Visual Studio's Graphics Diagnostics to debug some shader code, but when I try to "Start Diagnostics", I get an immediate access violation in dxgi.dll. This access violation appears to occur before my program's main function is even entered. I tried adding a Sleep just inside my WinMain function so I could attach a separate debugger, but this code was never hit. I opened one of the DirectX SDK sample programs with the same installation of VS2013 and the Graphics Diagnostics worked fine. I also tried using Graphics Diagnostics on my program on two separate PCs and they both threw the same access violation.

I suspect maybe it has something to do with my project configuration? It seems to be failing to establish a connection between the Graphics Diagnostics debugger and my program before the entry point of my program is called.

Any ideas are much appreciated!

[image: Error message and Call Stack]

Comment: Did you try to break and see the disassembly at the exception location? Looking at the addresses involved can give some clues.

Comment: I just did, but to be honest, I have no idea how to make any sense out of it. Is there something I can post that might be useful?

Comment: Well, for starters enable symbol downloading from MSDL in your debugger. Then post the call stack and the disassembled code at the exception location.

Comment: I configured VS2013 to use Microsoft Symbol Servers. Upon starting the Graphics Diagnostics, I could see that it was retrieving symbols files, but the same access violation happened and the call stack looks the same as what I originally posted above. I double-checked the folder I set as the local symbol cache and verified that it had downloaded dxgi.pdb.

Comment: What do you see in the Modules window? What DLL contains the address 7feddc0c2e8? Are symbols for that DLL loaded? What do you see in the disassembly window. Which instruction generated the access exception? What is in the memory/register(s) this instruction is using? In general, I would recommend using WinDbg instead of VS debugger. It will give you more system visibility.